# Should the natural or surrogate key be returned in an API?

Tags: rest, consistency, optimistic-locking

First time I think about it...

Until now, I always used the natural key in my API. For example, a REST API allowing to deal with entities, the URL would be like `/entities/{id}` where id is a natural key known to the user (the ID is passed to the POST request that creates the entity). After the entity is created, the user can use multiple commands (GET, DELETE, PUT...) to manipulate the entity. The entity also has a surrogate key generated by the database.

Now, think about the following sequence:

1. A user creates entity with id 1. (`POST /entities` with body containing id 1)
2. Another user deletes the entity (`DELETE /entities/1`)
3. The same other user creates the entity again (`POST /entities` with body containing id 1)
4. The first user decides to modify the entity (`PUT /entities/1` with body)

Before step 4 is executed, there is still an entity with id 1 in the database, but it is not the same entity created during step 1. The problem is that step 4 identifies the entity to modify based on the natural key which is the same for the deleted and new entity (while the surrogate key is different). Therefore, step 4 will succeed and the user will never know it is working on a new entity.

I generally also use optimistic locking in my applications, but I don't think it helps here. After step 1, the entity's version field is 0. After step 3, the new entity's version field is also 0. Therefore, the version check won't help. Is the right case to use timestamp field for optimistic locking?

Is the "good" solution to return surrogate key to the user? This way, the user always provides the surrogate key to the server which can use it to ensure it works on the same entity and not on a new one?

Which approach do you recommend?

Comment: For interested users, look at the chat with Gaz_Edge (the link to the chat can be found in the last comment of the accepted answer).

Comment: How would you respond to a PUT request that modified the natural key? Wouldn't that cause effective deletion of the target resource with a new one being created elsewhere? A move? But the http moved responses don't mean success, they mean retry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on how you want your users to user your api.

REST APIs should try to be discoverable. So if there is benefit in exposing natural keys in your API because it will allow users to modify the URI directly and get to a new state, then do it.

A good example is categories or tags. We could have these following URIs;

```
GET /some-resource?tag=1    // returns all resources tagged with 'blue'
GET /some-resource?tag=2    // returns all resources tagged with 'red'
```

or

```
GET /some-resource?tag=blue    // returns all resources tagged with 'blue'
GET /some-resource?tag=red    // returns all resources tagged with 'red'
```

There is clearly more value to a user in the second group, as they can see that the tag is a real word. This then allows them to type ANY word in there to see whats returned, whereas the first group does not allow this: it limits discoverability

A different example would be orders

```
GET /orders/1   // returns order 1
```

or

```
GET /orders/some-verbose-name-that-adds-no-meaning    // returns order 1
```

In this case there is little value in adding some verbose name to the order to allow it to be discoverable. A user is more likely to want to view all orders first (or a subset) and filter by date or price etc, and then choose an order to view

```
GET /orders?orderBy={date}&order=asc
```

**Additional**

After our discussion over chat, your issue seems to be with versioning and how to manage resource locking.

If you allow resources to be modified by multiple users, you need to send a version number with every request and response. The version number is incremented when any changes are made. If a request sends an older version number when trying to modify a resource, throw an error.

In the case where you allow the same URIs to be reused, there is a potential for conflict as the version number always begins from 0. In this case, you will also need to send over a GUID (surrogate key) and a version number. Or don't use natural URIs (see original answer above to decided when to do this or not).

There is another option which is to disallow reuse of URIs. This really depends on the use case and your business requirements. It may be fine to reuse a URI as conceptually it means the same thing. Example would be if you had a folder on your computer. Deleting the folder and recreating it, is the same as emptying the folder. Conceptually the folder is the same 'thing' but with different properties.

User account is probably an area where reusing URIs is not a good idea. If you delete an account /accounts/u1, that URI should be marked as deleted, and no other user should be able to create an account with username u1. Conceptually, a new user using the same URI is not the same as when the previous user was using it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What about the issue I described in the question?

Comment: I'm confused. I've tried to answer your question about exposing surrogate or natural keys... did i miss something?

Comment: Yes but my question was more driven by the issue I present. When a user uses natural keys with the API, he works with logical object (e.g. the entity with natural id 1). When a surrogate key is used, he works with the physical object (e.g. the entity with id 125648555845). The problem is that when the user gets an entity based on the natural key, it gets a physical entity. When he tries to delete it, he may delete a different physical entity with the same natural key.

Comment: That really just comes down to how you code it in your API. Just don't allow that mix up to happen. Just choose one or the other (natural or surrogate) and stick with it for each resource. Also, you seem to be mixing up some REST concepts in you question. Use POST when you are using surrogate keys (i.e. client does not know the key to use, its usually set by the application or database), PUT when you are using natural keys (i.e when the client knows the key to use)

Comment: When the user wants to create an entity, he sends a POST request with the natural key included in the body (this key has a meaning for him). The surrogate key is returned in the response body (along with the natural key). For all other requests that modify entities, the user must provide the surrogate key so that my server is sure to try to modify the intended entity (and not a new one with the same natural key). However, there also is the ability to query for entities using the natural key.

Comment: see additional text in answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70289/discussion-between-gaz-edge-and-mickael-marrache).

Answer (score 1):

Its interesting to see people trying to rediscover solutions to known problems. This issue is not specific to a REST API - it applies to any indexed storage. The only solution I have ever seen implemented is **don't re-use surrogate keys**.

If you are generating your surrogate key at the client, use UUIDs or split sequences, but for preference do it serverside.

Also, you should **never** use surrogate keys to de-reference data if a simple natural key exists in the data. Indeed, even if the natural key is a compound entity, you should consider very carefully whether to expose a surrogate key in the API.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned the possibility of using a timestamp as your optimistic locking.

Depending how strictly you're following a RESTful principle, the Entity returned by the POST will contain an "edit self" link; this is the URI to which a DELETE or UPDATE can be performed.

Taking your steps above as an example:

**Step 1**

User A does a POST of Entity 1. The returned Entity object will contain a "self" link indicating where updates should occur, like:

```
/entities/1/timestamp/312547124138
```

**Step 2**

User B gets the existing Entity 1, with the above "self" link, and performs a DELETE to that timestamp versioned URI.

**Step 3**

User B does a POST of a new Entity 1, which returns an object with a different "self" link, e.g.:

```
/entities/1/timestamp/312547999999
```

**Step 4**

User A, with the original Entity that they obtained in Step 1, tries doing a PUT to the "self" link on their object, which was:

```
/entities/1/timestamp/312547124138
```

...your service will recognise that although Entity 1 does exist; User A is trying a PUT against a version which has since become stale.

The service can then perform the appropriate action. Depending how sophisticated your algorithm is, you could either merge the changes or reject the PUT.

I can't remember the appropriate HTTP status code that you should return, following a PUT to a stale version... It's not something that I've implemented in the Rest framework that I work on, although I have planned to enable it in future. It might be that you return a 410 ("Gone").

**Step 5**

I know you don't have a step 5, but..! User A, upon finding their PUT has failed, might re-retrieve Entity 1. This could be a GET to their (stale) version, i.e. a GET to:

```
/entities/1/timestamp/312547124138
```

...and your service would return a redirect to GET from either a generic URI for that object, e.g.:

```
/entities/1
```

...or to the specific latest version, i.e.:

```
/entities/1/timestamp/312547999999
```

They can then make the changes intended in Step 4, subject to any application-level merge logic.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem can be solved either using ETags for versioning (a record can only modified if the current ETag is supplied) or by soft deletes (so the deleted record still exists but with a trashed bool which is reset by a PUT).

Sounds like you might also benefit from a batch end point and using transactions.